# Error handling in node-sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite

How do I handle error in sqlite3? For example, I have this simple code:

```
var stmt = db.prepare("update Tickets set " + columns + " where id = (?)");
stmt.run(req.body.id);
stmt.finalize();

db.close();
```

All four functions `prepare`, `run`, `finalize`, `close` has the potential to throw error. This is on my `express.js` server so I'm trying to put a `res.error()` statement somewhere to return result. I don't want to put it in all of them because I can run into a multiple res.setHeader error.

Is there a document on error handling practice with sqlite3? I can't find it in its API documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [api](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API).  Each of those functions takes a callback, whose first parameter is an error.

This will help you handle an error, but it will not stop your app from crashing.  In order to stop a crash, you'll have to use a `try/catch` , or preferably learn how to use [domains](https://gist.github.com/hueniverse/5167027).

Answer (score 2):

Errors are emitted on "error" event. 
you may want to try doing something like below after you initialise your db handle.

```
db.on("error", function(error) {
    console.log("Getting an error : ", error);
});
```